# django-allauth-2fa: Unexpected behaviour of accounts/two_factor/setup/ -> page reload after pressing 'verify'

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-two-factor-auth

I am trying to use django-allauth & django-allauth-2fa in my Django app.

My django-allauth app is set uo correctly - everything is working as expected.

However, when trying to set up django-allauth-2fa I ran into some issues: Configuring a two-factor authentification at accounts/two_factor/setup/ when I scan the QR code, input the token generated and press verify the page simply reloads with a new QR code instead of leading me to the next step in the Two-Factor configuration workflow. I can't figure out what my mistake may be, as I set up everything as written in the django-allauth-2fa documentation

My `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "==3.0.0"
pylint = "==2.4.4"
django-crispy-forms = "==1.9"
django-allauth = "==0.42.0"
django-allauth-2fa = "==0.8"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

my `settings.py` file:

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Local
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',

    #Third-party
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
    'allauth_2fa',
    'crispy_forms',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'allauth_2fa.middleware.AllauthTwoFactorMiddleware',
]

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'allauth_2fa.adapter.OTPAdapter'

...
```

my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth_2fa.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

And I also ran `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem on Ubuntu20 . Fix it with enbaling automatic sync date & times.